# Out of memory exception while parsing 5MB JSON response in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, out-of-memory

I am getting 5MB of a JSON response, I am downloading and saving in StringBuffer using a byte array with 1024 size.

To parse this response, I have to create a JSONObject with the parameter as a String. While converting response into String, I am getting an `out of memory exception(stringBufferVar.toString()).`

From service I will get the following response as max of 5 attachments each of maximum 5MB data in Base64 encoded.

Following is the response from service.

```
{"result":[{"attachment":{"name":"one.doc", "type":"document", "data":"base64 encoded data max of 5MB"}, {"attachment":{"name":"two.txt", "type":"text", "data":"base64 encoded data max of 5MB"} }] }
```

I will show the attachments in a list, when the user clicks on an item I have to save that attachment in SDCard. For this, how can I parse and save this huge amount of data in JSON.

Please provide any solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a Stream-based parser. in API 11+ there is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Below, there is gson http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Also, you probably need to save your service response as a file before reopening it with the JsonReader.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

My application build target 2.3.1(API level 9).

Also I tried with gson parser still the same OutOfMemory I am getting. 

InputStream is = helper.postData(url, parameters);
InputStreamReader ipReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
   
Gson gson = new Gson();
AttachmentDO attachmentResp = gson.fromJson(ipReader, AttachmentDO.class);

com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:694) - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: you need to use a stream based parser. I think gson has this capability, but not the way you use it

Answer (score 0):

Use Jackson

[Jackson Github](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

That should solve your issue.
But i will not recomment you to use huge data without pagination.