# Download video inside a JSON with android

Tags: android, json

How to download video inside JSON with android

I need to download a video encode in base 64 in android from a JSON

The JSON is something like this:

```
{
   "status"=0
   "result"="AAAAAHGZ0eXBtcDqyAAAAAG1wN...."
}
```

The video in the attribute result (it's more longer). I need to download the video and save it in a file.

When converting stream to string I have this error:

E/dalvikvm-heap(4964): Out of memory on a 53109242-byte allocation.

Because the file it's to big.

How I can do this? Because I can't save it in a string.

I tried this but It didn't work:

```
JsonReader readerJ = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                CapraboFileRequest file = null;
                readerJ.beginObject();
                int id=0;
                String text="";
                while (readerJ.hasNext()) {
                       String name = readerJ.nextName();
                       if (name.equals("status")) {
                         id = readerJ.nextInt();
                       } else if (name.equals("result")) {
                         text = readerJ.nextString().substring(0, 100);}

                Log.d("result", text);
                file=new CapraboFileRequest(id, text);
                setFile(file);
```

Comment: Who encodes a video in JSON?

Comment: +1 for doing your own research first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632667/out-of-memory-exception-while-parsing-5mb-json-response-in-android  but +1 for CommonsWare too. What's up with this API call?